# Angularjs, function only executable with a specified width

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

We just developed an app with a swipe function available for mobile platform. The site is developed with bootstrap.

I have this inside my controller.

```
$scope.customerSwipeL = function(){
    $location.path( "/customer" );
};
```

This is executable with your mouse to. You can drag you mouse from right or left(depending on the code function), the problem here when the user tries to mark something or(dragging) or selects a dropdown menu and tries to click away from it. The "customSwipeL" function is executed.

Is there any way to check a specific width in angular/JavaScript/jquery to only make the function executable when the width is x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "when the width is x". The width of what? In any case, I'm sure that the JQuery [.width() function](https://api.jquery.com/width/) will do what you need.

Example:

```
var screenWidth = $( window ).width();
```

Comment: I just tried this inside an  `$(function()`when the page loads. And a if function to check the `$( window ).width();` It worked and the function isn't available when the width is over 900! Thanks for the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the available height/width of the screen by using

```
window.screen.availHeight;
window.screen.availWidth;
```

A better method of accomplishing this might be to just check the platform being used. Simply checking for screen size isnt going to be very reliable in regard to your application's functionality. You should be able to use something like this:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     $location.path( "/customer" );
}
```

And it might even be worth simply executing that conditional statement once and storing the result somewhere with global access if you only need a simple boolean to represent whether the user is on a mobile platform or not.